# How to update Magento through Installatron

Tags: magento-1.9

Our host uses installatron as a way to download applications like Wordpress, Dreamweaver, Magento... etc, etc.

However, since Magento 2.0 got released, i've been waiting to upgrade it for our store as well, but Magento 2.0.1 got released recently, and i haven't seen it available in the installatron update menu.

Anyone knows how to upgrade magento 1.9.1.1 to Magento 2.0 or 2.0.1 through installatron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upgrade from 1.x to 2.x .

Magento 2.x is a completely new product with no direct compatibility with 1.x .

What you can do is to install a 2.x and use a migration tool to copy your 1.x information.

Have a look here for a detailed migration plan: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

Comment: Thank you! Now i only need to find out a few things related to our main website which runs on wordpress!